# Can I make an alternative branch the trunk in fossil

Tags: merge, branch, trunk, fossil

Is it possible to change the tag on a branch to make it replace the trunk without merging?

Update: I solved it, I also see now that it doesnt matter trunk is nothing more than a name, you can close it and use another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer.  Its very simple.

IN Web ui

- Go to the current trunk, select its current leaf and under other links select edit.
- Select Cancel Special Tag Trunk and Click update.

--

- Go to the current leaf of the branch you wish to make the trunk and select edit.
- Select "Add the following new tag name to this check-in:" and add tag 'Trunk'
- Select update.  Your selected branch is now also labeled trunk.